Azure private link in azure pipeline linux agent not resolving
We have an azure sql server exposed by private link to a linux virtual machine in peered vnet. We installed an azure pipeline agent on it, to be able to deploy items to the private network.
However, we have the following problem. When we login on the vm, and resolve the sql link, it resolves correctly to the private ip address for the SQL server. However, when we resolve it in the pipeline when executed by the agent, it resolves to the public ip address, which is disabled on SQL.
When doing nslookup for both, server points to 127.0.0.53 which is a systemd endpoint to forward queries, as i understood. So i would think they point to the same configuration.
Does anyone have an idea what we can do?
An example of the error:
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $Con -query "SELECT DB_ …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Reason: An instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
     | connection to SQL Server. Connection was denied since Deny Public
     | Network Access is set to Yes


Is the account you use to log into the VM and the account used by the agent to execute the pipeline the same account? If there are different, you can try to reconfigure the agent with the account you use to log into the VM.  Can you try using a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) instead of just a hostname, or try using a private IP address directly? Bu the way, you can refer this blog for more information.

Hey, we checked the user with whoami, and it said vsts. The user however does not seem to exist on the machine. When we run it interactively, with run.sh, it should run under our user, but it still says vsts. We tried adding resolving directly to ip in the /etc/hosts file, but it also gets ignored. Thanks for the link, i checked it out, but the dns server on the azure vm directly points to the 168.63.129.16 ip.

Hi @Rogue101, please check if the agent you are using is your self-hosted agent on the linux virtual machine.   It seems that you are using the Microsoft hosted agent because the 'vsts' user is typically used by the Microsoft hosted agent. I shared some screenshots in the answer. If possible, you can share your YAML  file and agent screenshots for troubleshooting.


we checked the user with whoami, and it said vsts. The user however does not seem to exist on the machine. When we run it interactively, with run.sh, it should run under our user, but it still says vsts.

As you said the user does not seem to exist on the machine, please double check the agent you are using. The 'vsts' user is typically used by the Microsoft hosted agent.

In my test on the Linux self-hosted agent, I run the run.sh with the account "azureuser". The Agent running as: 'azureuser'.

The information in my agent Capabilities:

